# Can't find files on Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, lamp

[Newbie Alert]
Greetings,
I've successfully deployed a LAMP VM/Instance on a project within GCP.  The Apache "It works" pops right up and life is good.

Except (of course), I can't find the /var/www/html/index.html to change it. This is blindingly obvious so, of course, I missed it.

Any pointers (pun intended) would be gratefully received.

Rick

Comment: How did you deployed the LAMP on Computer Engine?Have you followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-lamp) documentation?

Comment: I followed the 'package' instructions where you essentially pick the LAMP stack, it installs, and the Apache screen pops right up.  Hence, the simple, where's the index.html file question.  I built a local instance of a LAMP stack on my mac, worked perfectly, and could edit the index.html straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this answer in the hopes it helps somebody else.  As I mentioned, on an apache installation, you get the /var/www/html/index.html information on the default page if you successfully install Apache.

If you ssh or use Google Cloud Shell, it appears to get to the real "root" you simply type cd / and presto, you can navigate the way apache (or wordpress or any service) tells you to.

Hopefully, if you're new to virtual machines, this will help you.

Rick

PS: For an additional reference, you can use [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance) help center article about the most basic ways to connect to your Compute Engine instances as well.

Comment: Google Cloud Shell won't ssh to the instance automatically. Once you have launched it, run the command: `gcloud beta compute ssh --zone [ZONE] [INSTANCE_NAME]`

If you omit the zone, choose it interactively.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not on correct place, or trying access it trough main Cloud Shell.

Please go to

> Compute Engine -> VM Instances

On the line with your instance press SSH button.

When window is open, write :

```
cd /var/www/html
```

Press Enter

if no errors, than start editng the index.html